# What's you favorite starter HTML Template?

Tags: jquery, html, css, templates, bootstrap-4

While this shouldn't be the be-all-end-all for starter "Hello World" HTML templates.

I have been using this starter code to build barebones websites any other cool tags I could add to make it better?

I generally use Bootstrap documentationhttps://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/ and meta documentationhttps://ogp.me/ when creating intro starter code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
             shrink-to-fit=no">
        <!-- Og Tags -->
        <meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
        <meta property="og:description" 
  content="Sean Connery found fame and fortune as the
           suave, sophisticated British agent, James Bond." />
        <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
        <meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


        <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384- 
        q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" 
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384- 
        ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" 
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script 
    src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384- 
        ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" 
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Starter code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Otc23.png)

I also use linkedin.com/post-inspector/ to test my meta tags work concerning OG meta tag links.

I have started to dabble in react-bootstrap docs which is fun.

**On a side note** when using the OG meta tag image even though the docs on LinkedIn say 5MB, I find it doesn't work if 1MB or higher.

Comment: Just create your own...

Comment: google "html boilerplate"

Comment: @Zgood, I'll check the html boilerplate thing... didn't even know it existed. Thank you for this.

Comment: @Jonathan.B welcome! Also you can add your code as a text instead of an image - that would make things easier moving forward. Also try making questions more precise and less generic - that would give better answers from all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Every project is unique so I don't think there will be a one template to rule them all. So instead of a template here are some tips on how I usually do a project:

1. start with a clean html5

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

2. Know your [cdnjs packages](https://cdnjs.com/). You can find amazing and useful things like:

   - [**bootstrap**](https://getbootstrap.com/)
   - [jquery](https://code.jquery.com/)
   - [font awesome icons](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/get-started/)
   - [firebase](https://firebase.google.com)
   - [google font](https://fonts.googleapis.com)

*just to name a few.*

3. Seek inspiration over the web! Don't be afraid - html codes are public and you should take advantage of that as long as you make it yours.
4. Don't forget to add `meta` properties in the `head` to search engine optimization (SEO) the page when you are done.

**Edit**

You should also check [html5boilerplate](https://html5boilerplate.com/) *(thanks to @Zgood)*:

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I switch between Materialize CSS and Bootstrap CSS. I was posting introductory starter Bootstrap code with some [Meta tag Link](https://ogp.me/) meta link documentation of OG meta tags.

Comment: @Jonathan.B you are welcome. Let me know if this was helpful here. You should also change your question to be more specific as pointed out by the mods.